# Find solution of ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$ \frac{dy}{dx} + 2xy=y $

which satisfies the boundary conditon $y(3)=1$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + (2x-1)y = 0,$$
then using integrating factor $e^{\int2x-1 dx}$

I then get:

$e^{x^2-x}\frac{dy}{dx} + (2x-1)ye^{x^2-x} = 0e^{x^2-x}$
giving:

$\frac{d}{dx}{ye^{x^2-x}}=0e^{x^2-x}$

integrate both sides:

${ye^{x^2-x}}=C$

and thus:

$y=Ce^{-x^2+x}$

but I'm not sure this is correct as I have been given a different answer.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could divide throughout by $y$ and get a differential equation in $\ln(y)$ vs. $x$

Comment: Hint: it is a separable equation.

Answer (score 3):

Write it as
$$\frac{dy}{dx} + (2x-1)y = 0,$$
and *then* determine an integrating factor.

Comment: I edited my question there. Is that the correct integrating factor?

Comment: @Hsauce13: Yes, except that you should write $\int (2x-1) \, dx$ rather than $\int 2x - 1$.

Comment: please see my edits.

Comment: @Hsauce13: You haven't used the condition $y(3)=1$ yet.

Comment: How do I manifest that?

Comment: @Hsauce13: Determine $C$.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much.